# How can I check condition statement for ssh scp over the server

Tags: ssh, scp

```
myscp=$(sshpass -p testserver scp -rP 8888 root@localhost:/test/server/ ~/local/)
```

How can I add conditional statement to this line? If its pipe broken scp will stop/break otherwise if it's open for connection it will continue

```
if "$myscp" == 0; then
    echo "SUCCESS)."
else
    echo "**FAILED)."
    echo "$myscp"
    exit
    echo "Done........ 100.0%"
```

This example does not work

Answer (score 1):

First example saves the return code from sshpass:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

sshpass -p password \
scp -rq -P 22 user@localhost:~/src/path ~/dest/path

c=$?
if ((!$c)); then   
    echo "Success!"
else
    echo "Failed: exit code ($c)."
fi
```

Or you could use your command directly in an if-then statement:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if sshpass -p password \
scp -rq -P 22 user@localhost:~/src/path ~/dest/path; then
    echo "Success!"
else
    echo "Failed!"
fi
```

I **strongly** recommend that you do not use passwords but instead use key authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The `$?` variable is set to the return code of the last executed command

```
sshpass -p testserver scp -rP 8888 root@localhost:/test/server/ ~/local/
if [ $? == 0 ]; 
  then echo "SUCCESS)."
else
  echo "**FAILED)."
  echo "Exit code: $?"
  exit
  echo "Done........ 100.0%"
fi
```